# How to find the indirect relation through sql

Tags: sql, oracle

If my table `FRIENDS` is having two columns(`name, friend`) both of type varchar2 and data is like this

```
(Sam, Ram)
(Sam, Vamsi)
(Ram, John)
(Ram, Anand)
(Vamsi, Vijay)
```

So, I want a query which fetches all indirect relationship of a person e.g. for Sam, it will show  John, Vijay, Anand only not Ram and Vamsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select A.friend
from FRIENDS A
where A.friend not in (select B.friend from FRIENDS B where B. name = A.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
   f1.name
   , f2.friend as indirect_rel
from
   friends f1
   join friends f2 on f2.name = f1.friend
```

Comment: Thanks much for the quick reply :)